# Shortest way to get all the surname from map in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I am new  to groovy and was a bit struggling with the logic to get all the surnames from the map which contains list of users i.e. firstname and lastname.

The following is a question that am trying to answer:

"We have a list of User and User class has name,surname properties. Which is the shortest code to get a list of all the surnames?"

```
class Users {

  String fName
  String lName

  String toString() {
    return fName + " " + lName
  }

  static main(args){

    Users user = new Users()
    def keys = []
    def map = [[firstname:'michael',lastname:"turner",department:"finanace"],
               [firstname:'james',lastname:"spencer",department:"finanace"]]
    map.find{it.key == map[name]}.each{
      println keys += it.value
    }
    def counter = 1
    keys.each {
      println "Surname $counter - " it
      counter++
    }
  }
 i.e. : 
  user.setFName(pass fName from loop to Users class)
  user.setLName(pass lName from loop to Users class)
}
```

### Expected output onto console

surname 1 - spencer
surname 2 - turner

Comment: _"...and User class has name,surname properties..."_ -- But then your User class has `fName` and `lName` properties...  I'm not 100% sure what it is you're trying to do...

Comment: @tim any idea how to iterate over that map?

Comment: Does my answer below not answer your  question?

Comment: @tim- unfortunately not!

Comment: What are you looking for? Your code is quite confused and it's hard to know exactly what you want

Comment: @tim_yates see the expected output in question content!

Comment: The variable map is badly named as it is a list that contains maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be `map.lastname` as in:

```
assert map.lastname == ['turner', 'spencer']
```

Right, to get the output you (now) say you want:

```
map.lastname.eachWithIndex { name, idx ->
  println "surname ${idx + 1} - $name"
}
```

Or:

```
map.eachWithIndex { submap, idx ->
  println "surname ${idx + 1} - $submap.lastname"
}
```

Comment: The map is really a list of maps so this doesn't work - the power of variable names FTW.

Answer (score 0):

You have list of maps. We can convert that list of maps to a list of surnames and print it like this:

```
print map.collect { it.lastname }
```