# Iterate over a Map with custom elements in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

It might sound simple, but am kind of struggling with how to iterate over a Map with customised elements/key&value paired and print only lastnames. Any suggestion would be welcomed!

### code

```
def map = ['user1':[firstname:'mark',surname:'spencer',role:"developer"],
          ['user2':[firstname:'mark',surname:'melony',role:"developer"]]
```

### Expected output

lastname 1 : spencer
lastname 2 : melony

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortest way to get all the surname from map in groovy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444980/shortest-way-to-get-all-the-surname-from-map-in-groovy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
def map = [ 'user1':[firstname:'mark',surname:'spencer',role:"developer"],
            'user2':[firstname:'mark',surname:'melony',role:"developer"] ]               

map.eachWithIndex { key, map2, idx ->
  println "surname ${idx + 1} - $map2.surname"
}
```